# Webapp Builder - Threat Analysis Widget user permission issues

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

I've built a webapp which includes a Threat Analysis widget with a set of custom buffers configured. The buffer results need to be published to an existing Published Layer by my users. My user is a "Mobile Worker" user type and "Data Editor" role. They are able to edit the layers within the webapp using the standard edit tools, it just seems to be that publishing the outputs from this widget are not permissible. Any help would be appreciated. Screen shot of their error below.

They Assessment Buffers target layer is editable in the feature service settings.[image: Threat Analysis Widget Errod]

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates, your user type does not have permissions to create a service.
Per Esri's documentation, [Mobile Workers can't analyze, create or share items or data.](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/administer/user-types-orgs.htm#:%7E:text=Mobile%20Workers%20can%E2%80%99t%20analyze%2C%20create%2C%20or%20share%20items%20or%20data.)

This capability is allowed for users with the [Creator](https://links.esri.com/agol-help/user-type/creator) user type.

Comment: Thanks @evv_gis. I was worried that might be the case, but thought that as they were just appending the newly created buffers to a pre-existing, publish layer that they weren't actually creating a service, just editing an existing one.

Comment: @J_P - You could use Web AppBuilder Developer Edition to modify the widget, but in my experience, widgets developed by Esri can be cumbersome to extend.  However, if the user type licensing is a blocker, that would be a consideration to make.  You would need to identify the section of the widget where the service publishing takes place and replace it with an editing task to an existing service.